# Crop an image to make a process on the result

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to recognise the text written in an image, So what I want is to crop this image to make the process on the desired part only not all the image.
So any idea how can I do this ?
Here is the code am using on the image:

```
NSString*ret= [self DoProcess:capturedImage];
```

Here is I want to crop the captured image to make the process on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a CGRect for the part of image you want to extract and then use the below method:

```
CGRect cropRect = ...;
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([fullImage CGImage], cropRect) scale:fullImage.scale orientation:fullImage.imageOrientation];
```